# How to add further HTML elements to the elm code?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I try to implement further html elements like title (h1) or img src. I took an approach in my code with h1 one which is sadly not working. The buttons and the inputs, I found in the documentation but I don't really get (also from other tutorials) how to implement other elements.

```
-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ h1 [] [ text "todos" ]
    ]
    [ div[] [ input [ placeholder  " Team 1", style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", style "color"  "#488aff", value model.content] []
    , input [ placeholder  " Strength", style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", style "color"  "#32db64", value model.content ] []
    ]
    , div []
  [ button [ style "background-color" "#66cc81", style "color" "white", style "margin-top" "20px", style "width" "610px", style "border-radius" "25px", style "height" "60px", style "font-size" "30px", style "margin-right" "70px"] [ text "+ADD" ]
    ]
    ]
```

also this version doesn't work:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ div [h1 [] [ text "todos" ]
    ]
    ,div[] [ input [ placeholder  " Team 1", style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", style "color"  "#488aff", value model.content] []
    , input [ placeholder  " Strength", style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", style "color"  "#32db64", value model.content ] []
    ]
    , div []
  [ button [ style "background-color" "#66cc81", style "color" "white", style "margin-top" "20px", style "width" "610px", style "border-radius" "25px", style "height" "60px", style "font-size" "30px", style "margin-right" "70px"] [ text "+ADD" ]
    ]
    ]
```

Comment: Don't you get the compiler message "*The `div` function expects 2 arguments, but it got 3 instead.*"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of stray brackets in your code. I've reformatted it to produce the following:

```elm
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ h1 [] [ text "todos" ]
    , div[] [ input [ placeholder  " Team 1", style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", style "color"  "#488aff", value model.content] [] ]
    , input [ placeholder  " Strength", style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", style "color"  "#32db64", value model.content ] []
    , div [] [ button [ style "background-color" "#66cc81", style "color" "white", style "margin-top" "20px", style "width" "610px", style "border-radius" "25px", style "height" "60px", style "font-size" "30px", style "margin-right" "70px"] [ text "+ADD" ] ]
    ]
```

[Here is a diff](http://www.mergely.com/yVfTHwTu/) of your version and mine.

The `div` function takes two arguments: A list of attributes and a list of elements. Notice in my version above, there are some stray brackets removed that were causing compilation failures.